# Slow down bootstrap scroll-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrolltop

I have the scroll-top property on my logo and in my footer but the further I am from the top of the page the faster it scrolls up! So when I scroll-top from the bottom of the page its like a rocket! How would I go about slowing this down? I could not locate a specific enough answer

You can take a look at [live site here](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/)

Comment: Which plugin do you use for scrolling ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3, trying to find out exactly what it uses 1 second

Comment: Please share your code where you ask to the link to scroll to the top.

Comment: is is current in the navbar `<a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top">` and footer `<span class="ion-ios7-arrow-up up-icon scroll-top">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say how you initiate the scrolling effect so :

**1:** *Unbind your exiting onclick event :*

```
    $('.scroll-top').unbind('click');
```

**2 :** *Create new scroll event with wanted duration (here 5s )*

```
$('.scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 5000);       
});
```

**UPDATE** :

Replace :

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top">
<img class="logo" width="45" height="45" alt="lightning bolt logo" src="img/logo.png">
</a>
```

By :

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand custom-scroll-top">
<img class="logo" width="45" height="45" alt="lightning bolt logo" src="img/logo.png">
</a>
```

And add this JS :

```
$('.custom-scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 5000);      
});
```

**UPDATE 3 :**
The scroll effect is from your scroll-link.js file
Extract :

```
// scroll to top action
$('.scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');         
});
```

*You can too overide the 'slow' by the value you want*

Comment: Ah ok! This is great just changing the slow value worked perfectly!